# Multiple records from a join in one record

Tags: ms-access

I currently have two related tables:

```
Property
    ID
    Name
```

and

```
Checks
    ID
    Property
    Type
    ExpiresOn
```

The property field in the `Checks` table refers to an ID in the `Property` table.

Now there are different types of check, for this example I will stick to: Gas and Electric. So a typical `Checks` table would look something like this:

```
ID    Property    Type        ExpiresOn
----------------------------------------
1        1        Gas         20/07/13
2        1        Gas         21/07/13
3        1        Electric    22/07/13
4        2        Electric    23/07/13
```

Now what I would like to do, is display properties, with columns displaying the **last** check of each type. For example:

```
ID    Property.Name    GasExpiry      ElectricExpiry
--------------------------------------------------
1     Some Place       21/07/13 (2)   22/07/13  (3)
2     Another Place    null           23/07/13  (4)
```

I included the `ID` of each expiry date in brackets so it's easier to see what is going on. The `Checks` record with ID 1, didn't show up because it was not the last of that type for the particular property.

Right now I am doing this using Dlookup after failing to find a proper way to do this with joins. Of course, as `Property` gets more records Dlookup will start slowing down this query drastically.

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, I found the answer moment after posting this, but I'll keep it here in case anyone else has a similar problem.

The answer is to do a crosstab query. It is exactly as described in the question. You specify the columnn type and what you want to show in each field.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is to actually pivot the table so that rows become columns and the columns become rows.

Since, you have tagged this as an MS access database - you can refer to plenty of tutorials available online to accomplish this task.